# Book recommendation for formal, proof-based, theoretical books on time series and panel data

Tags: probability, statistics, book-recommendation, time-series

I'd like to ask you if there are any formal, proof-based and mainly theoretical books on time series and panel data. When searching for books on time series and panel data I got really good recommendations but all the books were more leaning towards the applied aspect. Either the books focused more on the computer science aspect (how to plot time series, how to execute Dickey-Fuller test, how to run regressions on panel data) accompanied with intuition but there are no proofs. Sometimes basic stuff is proven (like AR(1) is stationary if and only if the coefficient next to the laggued variable is between -1 and 1).

But, I've already seen a similar question asked here and the only recommended book that meets my needs is this one : Time Series Theory and Methods by Peter J. Brockwell, Richard A. Davis. The one that suggested this book said, I quote, "This used to be (still is?) the main reference for Time Series back in the day for those theoretically inclined." And so I'd like to know if there are any other books of the sort that are more recent or, even if they're old but were heavily used back in the days.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should let us know: 1) your maths level, 2) what are you looking for more in detail (you just said "theoretical books on time series and panel data"

Comment: I would like to know how to help you, since I am also looking for "real-maths-oriented" (as opposed to "dummy-maths-oriented") references.... Maybe I can point you to some books, but first you need to shed some light on the points above.

Comment: My maths level: measure theory (and all what it's related to it, Lp spaces, Fourier transformation), statistics (sampling, estimation, tests, Monte-Carlo, bootstrap... basic stuff), real and complex analysis, functional analysis, general topology, general algebra and linear algebra.

Comment: What I'm looking for exactly is a book that develops each model with details. Why the time series is stationary or not, how to get the trend..., are the estimators biased or not etc. When I say with details I mean something like, if we're going to use Dickey-Fuller's test than to develop exactly how it works and how to get the tables. I don't know much about panel data but from the linearmodels (python package) siteweb there are many models and ways to estimate the parameters. I book that I'd like is one that shows how to estimate these parameters "manually" (formulas and proofs of them).

Comment: I don't know if I was clear enough but to take Dickey-Fuller's test, every book I got my hands on or every article on a data science website / youtube video I've read / watched just develops what are the models that the different DF-tests work with and when we have stationarity and when not. But they don't specify why this DF-test works exactly with this model and with this condition and how do we get the table to compare the statistic and the p-value...

Comment: What's your background in probability?

Comment: I've studied probability theory (discrete then continuous) and measure theory in university. I've also had a class in stochastic elements but it wasn't much.

Comment: Ok understood - I ll try to write an answer with some references later today or tomorrow

Comment: @Tom sorry if this reminder bothers you. I tried to contact you through the chat but I wasn't fortunate... It'd be so cool if you could give some references before the weekend so that I could check them in the libraries. I hope I'm not bothering you.

Comment: Sorry I did not have the time yesterday. I hope my answer helps you somehow. PS. Would like to know how the chat works.

Comment: Thank your for the answer ! I found this post that explains how the chat works: [https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187426/how-do-i-chat-with-another-user-on-stackoverflow] and I believe you find _Talk in chat_ in the Activity section of your profile.

Answer (score 1):

I am not really in a position to answer this question, since I was about to ask something similar when I stumbled upon it...

Also, I am not entirely clear on what you are looking for exactly...

And not knowing the subject very well, I do not know what *I* am looking for exactly either...

Having said that, let's say we are interested in **mathematical** treatments of stochastic processes indexed by $\mathbb{Z}$ which are stationary in the $L^2$ sense (i.e. covariance stationary or wide-sense stationary).

Then I have selected these three books

- Shiryaev - Probability (Chapter 6)
- Koralov & Sinai - Theory of Probability and Random Processes (Chapter 15)
- Gikhman & Skorokhod - The Theory of Stochastic Processes I (Chapter 4)

There are really a lot of books trating these topics from the point of view of a statistician, engineer, economist and so on. But I find them so (mathematically) sloppy
that I basically cannot read them.

I will try to build-up some knowledge on the subject and hopefully add suggestions in the future.

In the meantime I hope this helps. Let me know.

Comment: Thank you ! I'll check them out when I can and I'll come back to you (it may take some time because I'm in France so finding english books is a bit difficult).

Comment: I hope somebody knowledgable on the topic will help you (and me) more...